# How can I change the range to A-C with this code?

Tags: excel, vba

This code gives me the target range as every cell in the A column. I'd like to change that to A,B and C. I've not been able to successfully do this. Also the date and time stamp should be in the D column. Here is the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    Next c
    Range("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A:C")` ?

Comment: @chrisneilsen that would be desastrous, as the `For each` loop will then post timestamps in a lot of cells.

Comment: @luuklag of course other adjustments will be needed.  It address the OPs request _I'd like to change that to A,B and C_

Comment: You could also use something more simple ie `If Target.Column = 1` for Column A, 2 for B, 3 for C etc.

Comment: @chrisneilsen that would be first half of the request, as it clearly states "*Also the date and time stamp should be in the D column.*"

Comment: @luuklag. It was a nudge in the right direction,  not a complete answer.  That's why it was a _comment_ and not an _answer_.  IMO the Q needs some fleshing out, a short on point comment was my way to see if the OP was willing to engage, which it seems they are not.  Since you feel so strongly about it, go ahead and provide a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes ready to engage. This is pretty important to me. I'm very new to excel and trying to figure this out among other things. Would be grateful for some guidance into this.

Comment: @captain In order to engage with people in comments you need to "ping" them using the @ symbol (as I've done here, for you). Otherwise there will be no notification. Reply to a specific comment (such as chris's) whether the suggestion helps and, if not, exactly how not. As has been mentioned, the question does not contain enough information for others to understand what's needed. You can use the [edit] link to supplement with additional information *in the question itself*.